# Unable to solve for x for an equation with independent variable in the exponent

Tags: r, matlab

I am trying to help a friend in finance research. I wish to solve, for x, the equation that looks like :

[image]

g,h,c,p,a,b are all constants.

I guess the first step would be to find it's derivative. This I did, using an online derivative calculator at http://www.derivative-calculator.net/. I got this :

[image]

Assume the above is equal to 0.

Further, I am trying to solve for x, assuming this is equal to zero. None of the online tools for 'solve for x' are able to do it. I have tried, Wolfram Alpha's online tool for 'solve-for-x', QuickMath, CynMath etc. All of them, 'cannot be solved'.

I am looking for a solution like :
x = some-expression-involving-g-h-c-p-a-b-and-e.

I have also tried the online Mathlab/Octave tools at CompileOnline/TutorialPoint. What can I do to solve for x, (preferably not having to install MathLab etc). Is there anything about these equations that render them incapable to be solved by Wolfram Alpha or such online tools for 'solve for x' ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question... do you want to solve df/dx = 0, f(x) = 0 or something else? And do you assume anything else about a,b,c,g,h,p apart that they are constants?

Comment: The value for f(x) will be supplied by the user, and is likely to range between 0 and 1 (excluding 0 and 1 themselves). 

I want to solve df/dx=0, as an means to calculate some formula to find out x, when someone gives f(x). 

f(x) and x are related as in the first equation given above. 

Values for a,b,c,g,h,p will vary, but they would have been determined by the time I would require x. 

Except that the independent variable appears there in the exponent and a derivative being involved, what I want to do is similar to solving, say, (over-simplified), y=3x+d by saying x=(y-d)/3.

Comment: This question really belongs on the Math site, but I suspect they would reject it in its current form due to the confusion between solving for $x$ in terms of $f$ and finding a zero of the derivative, which has *nothing* to do with solving the first equation. One finds derivatives of zeros as a first step towards obtaining *extreme values* of a function.  What really is your question, then: finding $x$ given $f(x)$ or extremizing $f$?

Comment: Thank you @arroba . Yes, I should've been more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* you're trying to solve $f'(x) = -g \, h \, e^{(h \, x + c)} - b \, p \, e^{(b \, x + a)} = 0$, then:
$$
\begin{aligned}
-g \, h \, e^{(h \, x + c)} - b \, p \, e^{(b \, x + a)} &= 0 \\
-g \, h \, e^{(h \, x + c)} &= b \, p \, e^{(b \, x + a)} \\
e^{(h \, x + c)} &= -\cfrac{b \, p}{g \, h} \, e^{(b \, x + a)} \\
\log [ e^{(h \, x + c)} ] &= \log [ -\cfrac{b \, p}{g \, h} \, e^{(b \, x + a)} ] \\
(h \, x + c) &= \log [ -\cfrac{b \, p}{g \, h} ] + \log [ \, e^{(b \, x + a)} ] \\
(h \, x + c) &= \log [ -\cfrac{b \, p}{g \, h} ] + (b \, x + a) \\
(h \, x + c) - (b \, x + a) &= \log [ -\cfrac{b \, p}{g \, h} ] \\
(h - b) \, x + c - a &= \log [ -\cfrac{b \, p}{g \, h} ] \\
x &= \cfrac{\log [ -\cfrac{b \, p}{g \, h} ] + a - c}{h - b}
\end{aligned}
$$
as long as $-\cfrac{b \, p}{g \, h} > 0$, $g \neq 0$, $h \neq 0$, $h \neq b$.

Comment: Solving $f(x) = y$ for some given $y$ is not the same thing as solving $f^\prime(x)=0$, so this solution would appear to be irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I agree that the question is very confuse but @Whirl has commented _"I want to solve df/dx=0"_ , thus the answer...